# Top Ten and Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

How do I run a query with VB that will return the TOP 10 results based on column appClickCount and update column appFAIList to 1 and anything below the TOP 10 will give the column appFAIList a value of 0?

```
Using sqlCon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ITCSDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim sqlText = "SELECT top 10 appClickCount " & _
            "FROM appTable" & _
        "UPDATE appTable SET appFAIList = 1"
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlText, sqlCon)
        cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this SQL statement instead

```
with t as (
  select *, rn=row_number() over (order by 1/0)
  from appTable)
update t set
  appFAIList = case when rn<=10 then 1 else 0 end
```

Your *vb.net* code is quite buggy though.  You're using **ExecuteScalar** which is intended to return a single-row, single-column result.  As written, it will give you the first appClickCount value.

The other issue is that using `TOP 10` in SQL Server without a corresponding ORDER BY means that it will ***quite arbitrarily*** (aka "randomly") return any 10 records from the table.

Comment: order by 1/0 DivisionByZero Exception?

Comment: @realnumber3012 Why don't you try it before commenting. Have a look at my profile. [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1c3b/2/2)

Comment: try in oracle. Not work) SQL SERVER doesn't install in my workstatiton

Comment: @realnumber3012 The connection string specifies a .mdf file using LocalDB, which means it is SQL Server. What does Oracle have to do with this?

Comment: ORA-01476: divisor is zero

Comment: @realnumber3012 Again, what does Oracle have to do with a SQL Server question??

Comment: Haha. Nothing. But my answer for SQL SERVER CLAUSE <UPDATE FROM>. My mind "order by 1/0" not good solution. But it's my mind

Comment: Putting 1/0 there seems rather cheeky. However, my +1 is not because of that but because the query works.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.appFAIList = 1
  FROM appTable AS a
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT top 10 appClickCount FROM appTable) AS b ON a.SomeField = b.SomeField

SomeField - may be primary key of your table
```